# Can I get the current URL without an address bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I use the code below to get the current url, and the hash ID it has after the forward slash for my domain. I would like to get the current URL of a page loaded in an iframe which means there's no address bar of course. How would I go about doing this?

the code I'm using now:

```
var currentURL = (document.URL);
var part = currentURL.split("SLASH")[1];
alert(part); // alerts "XdAs2" !!!
```

Comment: Frames have URLs exactly like other pages do.  URLs are not tied to address bars.

Comment: Since there's a few valid answers below to different scenarios: are you trying to retrieve the iframe's URL from **inside** or **outside** the iframe?

Comment: Good question, from inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, you can only get the url for as long as the contents of the iframe, and the referencing javascript, are served from the same domain. As long as that is true, something like this will work:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

If the two domains are mismatched, you'll run into cross site reference scripting security restrictions.

Comment: He's looking for *'the current URL of a page loaded in an iframe'*, not the URL of the parent frame afaics. Otherwise you're right of course, but from his description he just needs `window.location`.

Answer (score 0):

if it's an `iframe`  using jquery you can do

```
$('iframe').attr('src')
```

example :

http://jsfiddle.net/aFX8b/

Comment: OP didn't mention jQuery in his question, so please don't assume it available. Besides, this can be easily done in plain JS. And what OP really was asking for, was `window.location`.

Comment: @nietonfir , sorry but what is the jquery tag doing in his question :)

Answer (score 0):

The current URL is always in `window.location`, be it inside an iframe or in the root frame of the browser. The `window` object always refers to the current viewport.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/7QTvr/).